# Codeigniter and Smarty, Submit Form to Controller

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, smarty

I'm new to Codeigniter and PHP, I'm building a [simple login system](http://www.iluv2code.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html), but I'm having some trouble with the form submission. I'm using a Smarty for my templates and when I look at the HTML page source of the login page, the code is exactly what is in my login.tpl. This is what my tpl shows and also what the page source shows...basically the form doesn't know how to submit to the controller.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</h1>
   <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

How do I get the form to submit to the controller?

Comment: Is everything working without Smarty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form must point to a "controller/method".

```
form_open('controller/method');
```

### OR

You can alias `verifylogin` to `controller/method` in the `routes`

```
$route['verifylogin'] = 'controller/method';
```

---

```
form_open('verifylogin');
```

Comment: Thanks @Phillip. I changed my .tpl to use {form_open('verifylogin/index')} and {form_close()} and now it works. Thanks for the help!